# How does Node.js's `fs` module converts `PathLike` s to paths?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

In the Node.js there's an `fs` module, which has following type (in .d.ts):

```js
export type PathLike = string | Buffer | URL;
```

I encounter a problem where I need to convert PathLike to a plain path (e.g. `/etc/profile.d`). URLs can be converted using `url.fileURLToPath(...)` method, but how can I convert  `Buffer`?

Comment: [`Buffer.toString()`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_tostring_encoding_start_end) should be what you are looking for.

Comment: @Seblor alright, thank you.

Comment: Please remove the solution from your question.  Here on Stackoverflow, solutions belong in answers, not in the question.  You can write your own answer if you want.  Likewise, you don't add `[Resolved]` to the title here either.  People can see if there's an accepted answer to see if the question is resolved.

Comment: @jfriend00 ok, TIL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

`Buffer.toString()` for more details take a look at the [Node.js documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_tostring_encoding_start_end)